FOP pdf generation : fo:inline border overlapping issue
While generating pdf using xsl:fo,
I am getting overlapping border with fo:inline tag.
I am using apache-xmlgraphics-fop version 2.7.
Here is a code snippet
    <fo:block margin-top="4px">
        <fo:inline border-style="solid" border-width="1px" border-color="#E8EDF7" padding="2px" fox:border-radius="3pt">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce eu justo at quam hendrerit congue ac ac magna. Maecenas tincidunt vulputate justo, ut tempus lorem pulvinar a. Nulla fermentum metus sit amet metus tempus pretium. In massa sem, vestibulum a lectus eu, efficitur imperdiet odio.
        </fo:inline>
    </fo:block>

below is output :


Which version of FOP are you using? Your example has a single inline with border: what is the border overlapping with? Consider including a screenshot of the output to show what the problem is.

You need to increase the line-height of the fo:block.
line-stacking-strategy="max-height", the default (see https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#line-stacking-strategy), doesn't consider the border and padding on the fo:inline when positioning the line areas. (Still not sure why.)
If FOP supported line-stacking-strategy="line-height", then you could  set theline-height on the fo:inline, and only the lines with the fo:inline would have wider spacing.
